# Keep window when changing input sources?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have two windows on my windows 8.1 x86 pc. When I change the input source in one of them, so I can play PS3, I want the windows to keep the display setup.

In my case, windows treat the monitor like disconnected and move everything to the other one...? How can i fix this?

Comment: Windows is behaving like it should.  You actually are disconnecting the monitor by switching the input.  What version of Windows are you using exactly?

Comment: windows 8.1 x64

Comment: Update the contents of your question.  Be sure to update the tag to reflect the fact your using Windows 8.1